# Excel merge cell date and time

Tags: excel, datetime, ms-office

I want merge cell in Excel 2013 column date (2016-01-01) and column time (16:00:00),

How do I format cells to get **2016-01-01 16:00:00** ?

Here is my example https://postimg.org/image/clxeqb66h/

I get `42677 16:00:00`

Comment: 42677 is equal to 2016-10-24 if you convert number to date

Comment: @Andreas I dont need convert date to number...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using TEXT function.

As long as the date is on the A1 cell..

```
=TEXT(A1,"YYYY-MM-DD") 

=TEXT(A1,"HH:MM:SS")
```

Answer (score 22):

- **ADD** the two values

  - Dates and Times are stored in Excel as numbers of days since 1 Jan 1900 and fractions of a day for the time.  So to combine a date and time you would add them
  - Format the result as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is a very simple formula that can quickly help you combine date column and time column into one.

> Type this formula **= TEXT(A2,"m/dd/yy ")&TEXT(B2,"hh:mm:ss")**

```
A2 indicates the first data in date column, 
B2 stands the first data in time column, 
you can change them as you need) into a blank cell, 
and press Enter key, 
then drag the fill handle to fill the range you want to use this formula. 
See screenshot:
```

[image]

More :https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1538-excel-combine-date-and-time.html