# How to parse string timestamp into date

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2019

I have a text value that looks like this: `2019-03-25T06:05:00-07:00`. The general format is `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss-GMT`.  I don't care about the GMT part.  I am trying to use this text field to make time series scatter plots in excel.

I want to convert it to a timestamp as simply as possible.  I currently do this using a bunch of formulas:

Input: `2019-03-25T06:05:00-07:00`

1. Extract parts of time individually: `=value(mid(input_cell,12,2))`
2. Use `date()` and `time()` to get timestamp types
3. Add them together per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41164517/11163122
4. Use custom formatting to get a timestamp value

Output: `3/25/2019  6:05:00 AM`

In total this took me 8 cells and custom formatting.  This is too complicated.  What is a simpler/more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
=--REPLACE(LEFT(A1,19),11,1," ")
```

and format as desired

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the timestamp type is ISO 8601: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations

This led me to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26315881/11163122

Using the formula there, I found this to be a sufficient solution.  If anyone out there has a better method, please speak up! :)